# How to make a folder writeable

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, directory

I am working on a website using wordpress and WooComerce.
But when I go to system status it says this:
`To allow logging, make C:\inetpub\wwwroot/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/ writable or define a custom WC_LOG_DIR.`

Does somebody know how to solve this problem? And can make a little step by step tutorial for me? Because I'm a little bit nooby. I searched on google, but nothing worked, so... Here I am. Waiting for answers.

Comment: Log in with an ftp client like filezilla and change the file permissions for the directory to be writable  664

Comment: @chop62 He is on windows, can't make a directory writable by setting 666

Answer (score 4):

Paste the below line in wp-config.
This solved my problem.

```
define( 'WC_LOG_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/' );
```

Answer (score 0):

check below URL for ideal word press.

[Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following for setting permission on IIS7 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1164501.aspx?How+to+make+a+folder+writable